# How do web browsers monitor network of current open webpage?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, browser, tcp

Most modern browsers can display the network traffic of the currently open webpage and its dependencies in its dev tools.

When the browser sends the initial HTTP request for a webpage, it uses the response to display the webpage. A javascript file that the webpage depends on may send another request through AJAX.

Does the browser monitor the execution of the javascript file and display the subsequent requests in the original page's network log?

EDIT: For a bit of background, I'm trying to write a python program that will display all the network traffic generated by a webpage and its dependancies.

Comment: Take a look at Fiddler...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm mainly doing this for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

if you use chrome browser, you can use network feature on Developer tools.
through this feature, you can monitor all of network activities on page.
for monitoring execution of javascript, search firebug on google.

Answer (score 0):

> How do web browsers monitor network of current open webpage?

The short answer: the browser knows about all this, because it has to **prepare and send/receive all requests to the webserver**. That's his job, and involves much more than *monitoring* only.

> Does the browser monitor the execution of the javascript file and
>   display the subsequent requests in the original page's network log?

The browser not only has to monitor the execution of the script, it has to **execute the script** itself. The script then *forwards* the subsequent request to that same browser, thus no need for the browser to *monitor* the script to get that information.

> For a bit of background, I'm trying to write a python program that
>   will display all the network traffic generated by a webpage and its
>   dependancies.

Since this seems to be for educational purposes, you might want to start with writing a **plugin** for the browser to get an idea of what's happening inside (this will be mostly in JavaScript). In your plugin you can make **direct API-calls** to the browser-engine, or use **call-backs** to get notified when requests are made or pages/images arrive.

To monitor that traffic from within a **stand-alone application**, more work needs to be done. You'll have to sit somewhere in between the browser and your network card. This can be done by:

- Writing some kind of **proxy to catch and forward the HTTP-traffic** and direct your browser to that proxy.
- Using a library such as [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to catch all network traffic and **analyzing the TCP-packets**.